# Annotation Spring AOP AspectJ doesn't work with method from Managed Bean used in a JSF2 view?

Tags: java, jsf-2, aspectj, interceptor, spring-aop

This is the second time i ask this question. I don't find a solution.

Does AOP with AspectJ works with method from Managed Bean called from the view in JSF2?

Just want to know if it's possible.

I want to use an interceptor to send an email when a button is clicked, The click uses a  managed bean method to add something in my database. I want to intercept this method with a Service Mailer with Aspect J / AOP SPRING. I think there is a problem of context. Because in a main , the interception is working, the AOP is recognized but nothing happen when i click on the button on the jsf2 view.

Thanks

I already post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985756/does-aop-with-aspectj-works-with-method-from-managed-bean-called-from-the-view-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK AOP with @Aspect is now working, i don't understand really why...

I was first declaring my bean in faces config thinking they were injected in Beans.xml handle by spring.

```
    <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>patient</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.clb.genomic.lyon.beans.AddParticipant</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>participantBo</property-name>
        <value>#{participantBo}</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>sendMailBo</property-name>
        <value>#{sendMailBo}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

I moved the declaration directly in Beans.xml....and now it works.

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="patient" class="com.clb.genomic.lyon.beans.AddParticipant" scope="request">

    <property name="participantBo">
      <ref bean="participantBo"/>
   </property>

    <property name="sendMailBo">
        <ref bean="sendMailBo"/>
   </property>

</bean>
```